# How to make a ComponentGroup that stretches to fill the available space?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like a ComponentGroup to automatically stretch fill up the space (eg the width of the Form). I've tried various ways, e.g. enclosing it in a BoxLayout.y but haven't found a way that works. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

What I tried is this:

```
Form hiCG = new Form("ComponentGroup");

hiCG.add(BoxLayout.encloseY(ComponentGroup.encloseHorizontal(new Label("Text1"), new Label("Text22222"))));

//A hack to show what I'm after 
Label label1 = new Label("Text3");
Label label2 = new Label("Text4444444");
label2.setPreferredW(hiCG.getWidth() / 2); //using deprecated setPreferredW
ComponentGroup.setSameWidth(label1, label2);
hiCG.add(ComponentGroup.encloseHorizontal(label1, label2));
hiCG.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal component group can be scrolled to prevent the UI from failing in screens that are too big and as a result it doesn't grow to fit the size.

We can possibly add an adaptation to it that will work with grid layout but right now this is a bit "hardcoded". A workaround might be to do something like this:

```
Container c = GridLayout.encloseIn(2, label1, label2);
label1.setUIID("ToggleButtonFirst");
label2.setUIID("ToggleButtonLast");
```